# Ubuntu utility to unzip .azip?

Tags: zip

I just came across a file ending in `.azip` that I need to unzip.  Upon some Googling I found this:

https://azip.sourceforge.io/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/azip/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/azip/files/

It seems this is a Windows only program.  Is there an Ubuntu utility that will unzip .azip files?

I should mention I tried unzip on the off change it would work, it did not, here is the error:

```
$ unzip my_file.azip

Archive:  my_file.azip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of my_file.azip or
        my_file.azip.zip, and cannot find my_file.azip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: I've never heard of AZip before, but a moment ago I read that it uses the following compressoon methods: Reduce, Shrink, Implode, Deflate, Deflate64, BZip2, LZMA. The last one, LZMA could be crucial and maybe you could take a shot with 7Zip: `apt install p7zip-full`. Let's try with .azip or better remame to .7z . Maybe I will work or you would have to change some file preamble by hand. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have a .azip file we can test with?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "AZip" utility you found (https://azip.sourceforge.io/ ) just happens to be called that. It is just a Zip reader/writer. #redherring :-o

Similarly there is one on the Google Play store of this name too.

What was the source of the .azip file?  I find a mention of a .azip file format here https://www.agrisatwebgis.com/media/manuals/AgriSatwebGIS_BASIC_USER_GUIDE.pdf

What is the output of the Linux file command? This should help you identify the file. e.g.

```
 # more hello.txt
 Hello World
 # file hello.*
 hello.txt:    ASCII text
 hello.txt.gz: gzip compressed data, was "hello.txt", last modified: Tue Feb  9 22:20:02 2021, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 12
 hello.zip:    Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Hope that helps you. Regards, Andi